# Manage Windows in different ways on different workspaces/activites in KDE 4.5 possible?

Tags: kde, window-manager

I'm just wondering if it's possible to on one workspace (or maybe activity) to use Tiling, and use normal management on another, maybe change some grouping settings on another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as of KDE SC 4.5 this is not possible.